# How to transfer complete control from httpwebrequest to webbrowser using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I want to browse a page on webBrowser control after getting response from httpwebrequest that I make earlier. And I want to be able to click links on the webpage opened in the webbrowser control, to make it browse the next page. How can I do this? I am using C# WinForms.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You can get the response of request, but what about cookies? what about relative urls?

Comment: I have the response-header recorded from firebug. But I don't know how to move the session to a webbrowser control. I am actually trying to post an ajax request using httpwebrequest. I had asked my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921766/what-is-the-correct-way-to-send-an-ajax-post-request-using-httpwebrequest-in-c), but didn't get any response, so I thought I should just browse the page in a webbrowser and then click on the 'ajax' button and continue again with httpwebrequest.